# creating chart with css and javascript

Tags: css

i need to create a task list in the html page.using only css . i try using jquery,but it is not filled my requirement.for reference please check the image attached [image]

thank you

Comment: You are not asking any question... What do you expect? That someone will code it for you? Come on...

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Comment: Also, when asking questions it's usually good to add in either your relevant code or a live example for us to check out. There's not much we can gather from an image like that. :)

Comment: i not asking to code and give me . i am just asking give me any idea. i dont no how to start and where to start.i tried with jquery but it is not suitable to our requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can give you some ideas?

http://www.stillbreathing.co.uk/experiments/gantt/gantt-fixed.html

http://www.jlion.com/docs/gantt.aspx

http://www.jsgantt.com/

Comment: thanks spiral, the jsgantt link i tried , but creating chart using this one is have some problems. only one task can show on one line, multiple task cant show on single line. i mean task intervals like first two days AAA can do some BBB taks and aging after tow days AAA can do the same task.